# Is IntelliJ's "unnecessary parentheses" claim wrong?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, functional-programming

I have this method signature:

```
def fold[B](startValue: A): ((A, A) => B) => B
```

IntelliJ tells me that the parentheses in the lamba expression is unnecessary and that the signature can be written as:

```
def fold[B](startValue: A): (A, A) => B => B
```

Is this true? I've learned that we have right hand associativity, which means that

```
def fold[B](startValue: A): (A, A) => B => B
```

is the same as

```
def fold[B](startValue: A): (A, A) => (B => B)
```

But this to me does not seem the same as what I've expressed in the first signature. I want `fold` to:

return a function x that takes in a function y with two parameters of type A and returns a value of type B. I also want the function x to return a value of type B.

But the last signature seems to say that fold:

returns a function x which takes two parameters of type A and returns another function y which takes a parameter of type B and returns a value of type B.

This is clearly not what I want! In the first case, the function x returns a value. In the second, it returns a function.

Is IntelliJ really wrong here?

CONTEXT:

```
abstract class MyList[+A] {

  def fold[B](startValue: B): ((A, A) => B) => B

}
```

Comment: as an aside, why does fold not return a `((A, B) => B) => B`?, as what is now a `B` is presumably the accumulator, which will need to match the other `B`s

Comment: The proposal to rewrite `((A, A) => B) => B` into `(A, A) => B => B` is wrong - indeed, it's so obviously wrong, that it's hard to imagine that such a bug would be added to IntelliJ. Andronicus claims that the problem is not reproducible with 18.5.3. What version are you using, and what is *the exact code* that produces the wrong suggestion? Could it be that you've simplified your example too much?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I've added more context. This really produces the suggestion. Using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3

Comment: Current version is 2018.3.5. So, it seems that you've found a bug in some older version of IntelliJ, which by now has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As @JoelBerkeley noticed, defining such method in scala repl results in what you have described as expected behavior, so you're correct.

But from what I have checked in my intellij, no such suggestion appears. I'm using version 18.5.3 and official plugin for scala. Maybe your ide configuration is not up-to-date?

Comment: odd, if I put `def fn[A, B, C]: A => B => C = ???` into the REPL, it returns `fn: [A, B, C]=> A => (B => C)` which looks right-associative to me

Comment: @JoelBerkeley you're right, thank you for your comment, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: is operator associativity relevant here? this is to do with type signatures

Comment: I'm not sure, I would delete my answer and wait for a better one, but I already did it for some older answers and the option is blocked

Comment: Should this be a comment, or a no-repro close vote, or what?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm a bit lost, I cannot delete it, only flag as "in need of moderator intervention"